# Search multiple text files for string and copy line by appending it to summary_[date].log

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to search through a number of log files with different filenames. I want search for a hostname in each log and when a match is found have it copy that entire line to summary_[date].log and keep appending matching lines to it. So something I've started with is:

```
$captured = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path \\nas1\share1 -Include *.log |
where { ($_.Name | Select-String -pattern ('PC1','PC2','PC3') -SimpleMatch) } 
Now copy the line from each log file which contains the pattern and append it to a file with today's date stamp, so each week I'll have a file like \\nas1\share1\summary_03-07-2020.log
```

But this is not quite what I want as this will capture the filenames and append them to the $captured variable. It's also missing the code to copy any matching lines to a date stamped summary_[date].log

Each text file will contain, among other lines that start with a time stamp, something like this:

> 03-07-2020_14-36-17 - Backup of computer [PC1] is successfully
>   created.

So what I want is to search several text files on a share for several hostnames. If a text file contains the hostname have it append the line which contains the hostname to summary_[date].log. Lastly, since the matching lines will all start with a date/time stamp I need to keep the contents of summary_[date].log file sorted from newest date to oldest.

Essentially I should end up with a summary_[date].log every week that will look similar to this:

```
03-07-2020_14-36-17 - Backup of computer [PC1] is successfully created.
03-07-2020_13-21-12 - Backup of computer [PC3] is successfully created.
03-07-2020_11-36-29 - Backup of computer [PC2] is successfully created.
```

By doing this I get a summary of all log files from that day in a single file which I will then automatically email to a specific email address.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code selects a string from the file name, not the content.
To do what you are after, you can use simething like this:

```
$logFolder = '\\nas1\share1'
$outFile   = Join-Path -Path $logFolder -ChildPath ('summary_{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.log' -f (Get-Date))
$captured  = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $logFolder -Include *.log | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'PC1','PC2','PC3' -SimpleMatch).Line
} | Sort-Object  # sorting is optional of course

#output on screen
$captured

# output to new log file
$captured | Set-Content -Path $outFile
```

Next send this file as attachment like:

```
# use splatting for cmdlets that take a lot of parameters
$params = @{ 
    SmtpServer  = 'yourmailserver'
    From        = 'logtester@yourcompany.com'
    To          = 'someone@yourcompany.com'
    Subject     = 'Summary'
    Body        = 'Hi, in the attachment a summary of the backup logs'
    Attachments = $outFile
    # etc. 
} 

Send-Mailmessage @params
```

Comment: Btw I had to use the long method instead of splatting. I didn't know how to specify the port.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your log files?

This will work but it loads the entire content of all files into memory and maybe inefficient with large file and/or a large number of files.

If there is a large number of files or large files you could do some nested foreach loops and loop through each computer name for each file.

This also uses match rather than like in where-object, you can use. like if you get false positives.

```
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path "\\nas1\share1\*.log"
$ComputerArray = 'PC1','PC2','PC3'
$DateStamp =  get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy
$OutFile = 'summary_' + $DateStamp + '.log'

foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerArray)
{
    $FileContent | Where {$_ -match $ComputerName} | Add-Content -Path $OutFile
}
```

Comment: The script will run weekly, probably within hours of the backups so will this grab the one line from PC1 and put it into a new dated summary file, and repeat for PC2, PC3 etc. and keep adding it to the bottom of the same dated summary file?

Comment: Yeah it uses `Add-Content` which appends to the existing file for each loop.

Comment: .\collect.ps1 : File \\nas1\collect.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
\\nas1\collect.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.

This is the error I got from your sample. I've already ran set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy RemoteSigned on my system where I'm running the script from.

Comment: You need to set your execution policy. By default you cannot run unsigned Powershell scripts. Please read this link and decide which setting meets your security requirements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thanks. I did that but it didn't take the first time for some reason. Did it again now and I've confirmed it's fine.